# how stub string prototype trim() with sinon testing

Tags: javascript, testing, sinon, trim, stub

I have a question to stub a string proptype [trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim).

This is a bit of my code :
File Ask.js :

```js
class Ask {
    constructor(s)
    {
        prompt = s
    }
    
    order(){
        var c = prompt("say something")
        
        switch (c.trim())
        case "hi":
            ...
        break;
        ...
    }
}
```

Files AskTest.js

```js
describe('order', function(){
    it('...', function(){
        const prompt = sinon.stub()
        
        prompt.onFirstCall().returns("hi")
        
        ask = new Ask(prompt)
        
        ask.order()
        
    })
}
```

I need of the trim() in the code

```
c.trim()
```

Whitout the trim the test works fine
But with i have got this error :
**TypeError : Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'trim')**

i try that :

var trim = sinon.stub(String.prototype, 'trim')
prompt.onFirstCall().returns("hi").trim

But not works

The question is how can i mock trim for the test works ?

Sorry to my English and thanks

Comment: The problem is not that you need to stub a `String.prototype` method. The problem is that `c` is not a string.

Comment: Your variable `prompt` should be an instance property and your variable `ask` is missing a declaration.

Comment: Bergi i forget to write i require prompt in Ask.js

```
var prompt = require('synchro-promt')
```

Ok thanks i will go think about that, the variable ```c```` if is not a string, and i will be back if i find a solution

Comment: "*I require prompt in Ask.js, `var prompt = require('synchro-promt')`*" - but then you overwrite that module-scoped variable every time you create an instance, in your constructor, assigning `prompt = s`. Don't do that.

Comment: i verify, prompt return well a string